# Erro ao utilizar a classe apache HttpClient

Tags: android

Estou tentando desenvolver um app no qual irá fazer comunicação com webservice, porem na hora que tendo utilizar as classes HttpClient ou outras relacionadas a biblioteca apache dá erro como não existe, já coloquei manualmente os arquivos .jar na pasta lib mas continuou apresentando o erro.

Comment: Posta o código aqui para facilitar a análise. Recomendo também a leitura de [**Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo   seguinte    adicione as seguintes bibliotecas ao `build.gradle` no bloco `dependencies`.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

Comment: amigo essas duas bibliotecas acima mencionadas por mim funcionam que e uma beleza em todos os APIs,  eu tenho um aplicativo criado que utiliza essas bibliotecas  e o mesmo nunca gerou erros

Answer (score 4):

Na versão Android 6.0(API level 23) foi removido o suporte para o cliente *HTTP Apache*.

Em vez dela use a classe [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Esta API é mais eficiente, pois reduz o uso da rede e minimiza o consumo de energia.

Para continuar usando as APIs do *Apache HTTP*, você tem de declarar a seguinte dependência no arquivo *build.gradle*:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Informação obtida [aqui](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: Você teria algum material para indicar sobre o uso da classe HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: Veja na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) e este [exemplo](http://romarconsultoria.blogspot.pt/2011/11/usando-httpurlconnection-para-receber.html) de utilização que encontrei procurando no google.

Comment: Quem negativou pode por favor explicar a razão.