# Enviando parâmetros por url android

Tags: android, post

Tenho um aplicativo android rodando e preciso enviar alguns paramentos por URL de forma rápida e fácil de ser executado.

Eu utilizo esse código para executar essa função, porem já esta obsoleto e as vezes não funciona como deveria! Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

```
public void sendRegisterTime(String id, String horaRegister, String image){
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ipConnectionServer+dirInsertTimer);

    try{
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> valores = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cod", id));
        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hora", horaRegister));
        valores.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img", image));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(valores));
        final HttpResponse resposta = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                   if(EntityUtils.toString(resposta.getEntity()).equals("success")){
                       successLayout();
                   }else{
                       failedLayout();
                   }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: da uma olhada nessa lib: https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb

Comment: Relacionado [Erro ao utilizar a classe apache HttpClient](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95391/2541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor lib para fazer isso é [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Esta lib é muito fiável ... da square.